# Using STOMP Over WebSocket (stomp.js) connecting to Artemis Server, but setting selector is ineffective

Tags: stomp, activemq-artemis, stomp-websocket

The duration addressing and queue setting of Artemis server is:

```xml
<address-settings>
    <address-setting match="#">
        <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
        <auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
    </address-setting>
</address-settings>
<addresses>
    <address name="test">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="abc.filter"/>
        </anycast>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

The javascript client used to connect to the queue and subscribe message is:

```xml
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="stomp.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let client = Stomp.client("ws://127.0.0.1:61613");
        // this allows to display debug logs directly on the web page
        client.debug = function (str) {
            console.log(str);
        };
        // the client is notified when it is connected to the server.
        // let headers = {"ack": "client", "selector": "location = 'Europe'"};
        let connected = function(frame) {
            client.subscribe("/test", function(message) {
                $("#messages").append("<p>" + message.body + "</p>\n");
            }, {"durable-subscription-name": "filter", "selector": "tag = 'aaa'"});
        };
        client.connect({"client-id": "abc"}, connected);
    });
</script>
```

Although the client sets the `selector` to filter the message, the client can receive message with other tags, such as `bbb`:
[image: The ineffective of selector]

However, the similar selector is effective in Java:

```java
class Consumer {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory;
    Connection connection;
    Session session;
    Queue queue;
    MessageConsumer consumer;

    public Consumer() {
        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            queue = session.createQueue("test::abc.filter");
            consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "tag='aaa'");
            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(Message message) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("C-" + tag + " RECEIVING > " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ask why the `selector` does not work in stomp-websocket?

The code to send message is:

```java
    public Producer() {
        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            queue = session.createQueue("test::abc.filter");
            producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send(String tag, String msg) {
        try {
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
            message.setStringProperty("tag", tag);
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("SENDING > " + message.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using FQQN? I ask because it's not really common to use FQQN & STOMP.

Comment: Your JMS consumer is using a *queue* which has anycast semantics in the broker. However, your STOMP subscriber is using a durable subscription which in JMS is used on topics which have multicast semantics in the broker. This seems kind of strange and it's not clear what your desired use-case is here. Can you clarify specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for helping. I'm a beginner of MQ, I think I do not use multicast in STOMP subscriber? In my scenario, I have some fixed running services (such as Text classification), which need message queues to recieve their tasks and response results from difference clients, so I want to use durable queues to perform the role. The selector is the id of clients.  Clients are diversity, so I need STOMP in websocket to let web app can use these services.

Comment: The code to send message, I have added to the end of post in above